# JSF2 built in ajax support error : f:ajax not found

Tags: jsf-2

Tried Mojarra -  2.0.8, 2.1.6 , MyFaces 2.0.11,2.1.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<body> 
   <h:form> 
      <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText> 
      <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me"> 
         <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" /> 
      </h:commandButton> 
      <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}"/></h2> 
   </h:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have semicolons between the namespace declarations in `html` tag?

Answer (score 0):

The XML namespaces are invalid. You've removed the `http://` prefix from them all. This is not right.

Here's a rewrite:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form> 
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText> 
            <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me"> 
                <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" /> 
            </h:commandButton> 
            <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}"/></h2> 
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Note that you also forgot the `<h:head>` component. This generates a HTML `<head>` element which allows JSF to auto-include the necessary JS and CSS files. In case of `<f:ajax>`, the JSF-supplied `jsf.js` file needs to be (auto)included, otherwise you will face a JS error after the page is been loaded.